# Jetty logs duplicated in start.log and solr.log

Tags: solr, jetty

I'm starting Solr using Jetty. I can see `start.log` and `solr.log` both are being logged to the same directory with the same content.

This is my Jetty settings file:

```
JETTY_HOME=/opt/solr/solr-4.10.0/example

JETTY_LOGS=$JETTY_HOME/logs
```

How do I disable `start.log` and only keep `solr.log`?

Comment: Fixed grammar and removed unnecessary code tags around the product names. It should be easier to read and understand now.

Answer (score 2):

`start.log` only exists for the time period when Jetty is initiated and up to the point where standard Jetty logging takes over.

`start.log` is created and managed by [`org.eclipse.jetty.start.StartLog`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.3.v20150827/jetty-start/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/start/StartLog.java), which [re-routes `System.err` and `System.out` to its log file](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.3.v20150827/jetty-start/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/start/StartLog.java#L169-L170).  Once standard logging kicks in, that logging infrastructure will re-route `System.err` and `System.out` for its own purposes.

The creation of `start.log` is established by the presence of [`--start-log-file=<filename>`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.3.v20150827/jetty-start/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/start/StartLog.java#L126) on the `start.jar` command line.

The `jetty.sh` script adds the `--start-log-file=<filename>` argument by default, with no way of disabling it (short of manually editing that file)

Comment: Thanks Joakim!
Yes, start.log is fine that jetty logs until standard logging kicks in. But the continued logging  of queries, commits is happening in both places, it continues in start.log as well as in solr.log. From what I understand, start.log should stop logging once solr.log starts logging right?